# c# asp net validation how protect string from www

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I create simple user model. And I need protect FirstName and LastName that user cannot post some web adress with www like [www.somedomain.com](http://www.somedomain.com).

How to do that ?

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the RegularExpression validation rules. So you need a regular expression which identifies an URL and you want a negative response of that. You can read all about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0

However. Although I understand your reasoning for this you might want to consider the (very human) question: Why? And this is more for your consideration and not really technical.

If a person really want to enter a domain-name for instance stackoverflow. I could also try firstname `StackOverflow` lastname `Com` and be done with it.
Secondly if you tumble down this rabbithole too far you might want break the rules of the real world. For instance you want to filter specific (swear) words. Or Lastname should be at least 2 characters (for testing users using A B C).

But in the real world this can happen, some (non English) countries may have first or last names which are (in English) for instance a swear word.
Besides that there are millions of people who actually have a first or last name with just a single character.

So although I really understand your requirement I'd opt to leave the required attribute and be done with it.